# How do I make SwiftUI textfield partly non removable?

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield

Im trying to do a textfield with the country code prefix that cannot delete from textfield. After select the country, the country code as the prefix cannot be delete and the user still able to key the contact number behind the country code prefix. Now I just code until assign the code into the textfield but the country code is still removable.

```
TextField("Number", text: $reg.mobile)
         .keyboardType(.numberPad)
         .padding()
         .background(Color.textfieldColor)
         .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
         .padding(.trailing,10)
```

In this textfield I init the reg.mobile with country code. But the code is removable. I try

```
class RegisterPost: ObservableObject, Codable{
    @Published var mobile = "60"
    //remaining
```

```
if expand {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.expand.toggle()
                        self.reg.mobile = "60"
                    }) {
                        HStack{
                            Text("+60")
                                .font(.subheadline)
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(5)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.expand.toggle()
                        self.reg.mobile = "65"                        
                    })
```

I try to assign country code into reg.mobile and make it as prefix of textfield and unremovable.
[Add a prefix to TextField in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60427656/add-a-prefix-to-textfield-in-swiftui) in this question I can only found a fixed prefix but not dynamic. Looking for suggestion is there anyway to do what I want?

Comment: It is possible to make prefix unremovable (at least persistent) but input caret will be moved anyway, because TextField has no API to manage input. So it is better to do what you want based on UITextField.

Comment: You can subscribe to the published string via Combine framework and replace the string with the prefix if the user tries to delete it.

Comment: @Asperi ya I found the problem of input caret last time. Tq for explanation.

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution would be to combine a Text and a TextField view into a new view

```
struct PhoneNumberField: View {
    let code: String
    @Binding var number: String

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(code)
            TextField("Number", text: $number)
        } 
        .padding()
        .background(Color.textfieldColor)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
        .padding(.trailing,10)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `.onChange` modifier to check if the prefix was changed and change it back

```
TextField("Number", text: $reg.mobile)
    .onChange(of: reg.mobile) { newValue in
        !newValue.hasPrefix("60") {
            reg.mobile = "60"
        }
    }
```